# XML Serialization of the default values of optional attributes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I have a set of classes build using xsd.exe, and I am trying to serialise them. However, an attribute is not being included in the resulting XML. Here is part of the schema where the problem lies.

```
<xsd:element name="Widget">
    <xsd:complexType>
        /* sequence removed for brevity */
        <xsd:attribute name="Version" type="Version" use="optional" default="1.1"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:simpleType name="Version">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="1.0"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="1.1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

xsd.exe generated a property called "Version" on a "Widget" class and another property called "VersionSpecified", but this not appear to generate the attribute when I serialize even when set to true:

```
[XmlAttributeAttribute]
[DefaultValueAttribute(Version.Version_1_1)]
public Version Version { get; set; }

[Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute]
public bool VersionSpecified { get; set; }
```

And this is the enumeration on which it is based:

```
/// <remarks/>
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[Serializable]
public enum Version
{
    [XmlEnumAttribute("1.0")]
    Version_1_0,

    [XmlEnumAttribute("1.1")]
    Version_1_1,
}
```

Code snippet as per request

```
Widget widget = new Widget();
widget.Version = Version.Version_1_1;
widget.VersionSpecified = true;    

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(widget.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(/*Memory Stream object*/, widget);
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why the serialization refuses to introduce the attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because you specified the default value as "1.1".  The serialiser will not create the element/attribute when the property is equal to its default value.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to force it to serialize an optional attribute with a default value, where the value is explicitly set in code before calling serialize, like in the example in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the VersionSpecified flag to true before serializing. That's how it knows whether or not this optional attribute is to be serialized.

Comment: Hi John, doing exactly that just prior to serializing. There's nothing special I need to do to the serializer itself, is there?

Comment: Please show the code you use for serializing, and no, you shouldn't have to do anything else special.