# (de)serialization of changed objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I'm using C#, .NET Framework 4.0.
I have class which consists of two strings and few int fields.
In my program I serialize/deserialize objects of that class, and everything works fine, but in future this class will need to be changed multiple times, by adding new int fields. How can I make old saved data compatible with new objects of same class, for example I need to do an for loop through all objects of that class, including old ones which don't have new int fields set?

Comment: How are you serializing / deserializing the data?

Comment: if (File.Exists("C:\\UvozIzvoz\\stanje.bin"))
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\UvozIzvoz\\stanje.bin", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                    stanje = (Stanje)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }

Comment: I use binaryFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Json for that. That way when you add new properties to your class you won't need to change any of the load / save code. I usually use [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for that.

Comment: this answer seems simplest! thanks mate, and thanks to everyone who tried to answer, I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answers!

Answer (score 0):

How about making the new attributes optional with corrseponding annotation?
[XML Serialization of the default values of optional attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411542/xml-serialization-of-the-default-values-of-optional-attributes)

Or you could create code only to migrate between the two versions (load by the old way and convert to new version).